# Separable ODE with rational degrees denominator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to get the exact solution of the ODE as below:

$y'(x)=1+y(x)+y(x)^{5/3}$.

That is,

$\int{\frac{1}{1+y(x)+y(x)^{5/3}}dy}=\int{dx}$

I found that this is a special case of Chini equation.

The Chini equation is written as below:

$y'(t)=f(x)+g(x)y(x)+h(x)y(x)^{n}$

It is known that Chini equation does not have generalized exact solution, but in some special cases, the exact solutions exist (E. Kamke).
If the Chini invariant is independent of $x$, the solution can be derived in a straightforward way. The Chini invariant is defined as below (by [A nonlinear first order ordinary differential equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ytnat-fracdyt/41181#41181?newreg=8f875d8964654003b5b08b5af9b8dbe2)):

$ f(x)^{-n-1}h(x)^{-2n+1}(f(x)\frac{dh(x)}{dx} - h(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx} + nf(x)g(x)h(x))^{n} n^{-n}$

or from other page, the sign of the last term is different ([Solving ODEs of the Form Chini](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FChini))

$ f(x)^{-n-1}h(x)^{-2n+1}(f(x)\frac{dh(x)}{dx} - h(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx} - nf(x)g(x)h(x))^{n} n^{-n}$.

In my case, $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are all constants and $n$ is a rational number, so it satisfies the condition of the Chini invariant with no regards to the sign.

Therefore it seems like the exact solution can be derived from Chini equation. Or the separable ODE might be the other option, but I am stuck. Do someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to switch variables and write
$$x+c=\int \frac {dy}{1+y+y^{\frac 53}}=3\int \frac{ t^2}{t^5+t^3+1}\,dt$$
$$\frac{ t^2}{t^5+t^3+1}=\frac{ t^2}{\prod_{i=1}^5 (t-r_i)}=\sum_{i=1}^5\frac {A_i}{t-r_i}$$
$$x+c=\sum_{i=1}^5 A_i\, \log(t-r_i)$$ From a formal point of view, I think that this is correct. From a practical point of view, it would not be very pleasant (I suppose). I should avoid thinking about a possible inversion.

Comment: Would you tell me how you derived the second and third equality equations at the second line?

Comment: Referring to the solution from WolframAlpha, the solution looks similar, but I need to figure out A_i, too